# How to replace a given substring with "" from a given string?

Tags: java, liferay

I went through a couple of examples to replace a given sub-string from a given string with `""` but could not achieve the result. The String is too long to post and it contains a sub-string which is as follows:-

```
/image/journal/article?img_id=24810&amp;t=1475128689597
```

I want to replace this sub-string with "".Here the value of  `img_id` and `t` can vary, so I would have to use regular expression. I tried with the following code:-

```
String regex="^/image/journal/article?img_id=([0-9])*&amp;t=([0-9])*$";
content=content.replace(regex,"");
```

Here content is the original given string. But this code is actually not replacing anything from the `content`. So please help..any help would be appreciated .thanx in advance.

Comment: 1. You probably don't need regex. 2. `replace()` doesn't take a regex as input

Comment: You can try to use `.replaceAll` method... But I recommend you use Pattern class to compile your regex and call this class methods to process your expressions.

Comment: I need regex..please specify how to use it.

Comment: You used `^` and `$` markers, yet you say it's a _substring_ you're matching. Study the regex semantics before using them.

Comment: I am not saying regex as substring. substring is "/image/journal/article?img_id=24810&amp;t=1475128689597"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `replaceAll` works in nice way with regex

```
content=content.replaceAll("[0-9]*","");
```

Code

```
String content="/image/journal/article?img_id=24810&amp;t=1475128689597";
content=content.replaceAll("[0-9]*","");
System.out.println(content);
```

Output :

```
/image/journal/article?img_id=&amp;t=
```

Update : simple, might be little less cozy but easy one

```
    String content="sas/image/journal/article?img_id=24810&amp;t=1475128689597";
    content=content.replaceAll("\\/image.*","");
    System.out.println(content);
```

Output:

```
sas
```

If there is something more after `t=1475128689597/?tag=343sdds` and you want to retain `?tag=343sdds` then use below

```
    String content="sas/image/journal/article?img_id=24810&amp;t=1475128689597/?tag=343sdds";
    content=content.replaceAll("(\\/image.*[0-9]+[\\/])","");
    System.out.println(content);
    }
```

Output:

```
sas?tag=343sdds
```

Comment: OP wants to remove the entire `/image...` substring from a larger string he didn't post, not just the variable parts.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik oops i thought something else , let me edit my answer . thanks dude

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to replace the substring of the URL with two quotations like so:

`/image/journal/article?img_id=""&amp;t=""`

Then you need to add escaped quotes `\"\"` inside your content assignment, edit your regex to only look for the numbers, and change it to replaceAll:

```
content=content.replaceAll(regex,"\"\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**Java regex Utility**](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-regex/matcher.html) to replace your String with `""` or (any desired String literal), based on given pattern (regex) as following:

```
String content = "ALPHA_/image/journal/article?img_id=24810&amp;t=1475128689597_BRAVO";
String regex = "\\/image\\/journal\\/article\\?img_id=\\d+&amp;t=\\d+";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(content);
if (matcher.find()) {
    String replacement = matcher.replaceAll("PK");
    System.out.println(replacement); // Will print ALPHA_PK_BRAVO
}
```